# Hamiltonian with 3/2 spin

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin

For particles with 3/2 spin, given this Hamiltonian,
$$H = \frac{\omega}{\hbar}\left(S_y^2 +3S_z^2\right),$$
(where $S_y$ and $S_z$ are the spin operators for their respective axes), and this $t=0$ state,
$$|\psi(t=0)\rangle = \frac{1}{2}\left(3^\frac{1}{2}\left|S_z= \frac{3}{2}\hbar\right\rangle +i\left|S_z=-\frac{1}{2}\hbar\right\rangle\right),$$
why is it true that the energy observable at $t>0$ is the same as at $t=0$ (E is constant)? What criteria should I check to see that?

Comment: This is true for all states undergoing unitary evolution, per the Schrödinger equation. The equality is in terms of the expectation value of the energy observable

Comment: im sorry but i dont quit follow. you mean the equality for psi at t=0? what makes this specific case unitery? im trying to generelize to other instances

Comment: Energy is always conserved unless the Hamiltonian is time dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial average energy is $E(0)=\langle \psi(0)| H|\psi(0)\rangle$ and the average energy at any given point in time is $$E(t)=\langle \psi(t)| H|\psi(t)\rangle.$$ By the Schrödinger equation,
$$|\psi(t)\rangle=e^{-i H t/\hbar}|\psi(0)\rangle,$$ so we conclude that
\begin{aligned}E(t)&=\langle \psi(0)|e^{iHt/\hbar} H e^{-iHt/\hbar}|\psi(0)\rangle\\
&=\langle \psi(0)| H e^{iHt/\hbar}e^{-iHt/\hbar}|\psi(0)\rangle\\
&=\langle \psi(0)| H |\psi(0)\rangle\\
&=E(0),\end{aligned} where we have used that all functions of $H$ commute with each other. None of this had to make reference to your specific initial state or Hamiltonian, other than that the Hamiltonian is independent of time.